# Zipalign not working?

Tags: android, cordova, build

I created android app using cordova plugin, I signed him and now I try compress .apk via zipalign

```
./zipalign -v release.apk WoW.apk
```

And after running this command I get this:

```
Zip alignment utility
Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

Usage: zipalign [-f] [-p] [-v] [-z] <align> infile.zip outfile.zip
       zipalign -c [-v] <align> infile.zip

  <align>: alignment in bytes, e.g. '4' provides 32-bit alignment
  -c: check alignment only (does not modify file)
  -f: overwrite existing outfile.zip
  -p: page align stored shared object files
  -v: verbose output
  -z: recompress using Zopfli
```

What's wrong? Why zipalign not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...

```
./zipalign -v 4 release.apk WoW.apk
```

Comment: you should add comments on your answer to tell what's missing.